# Не могу создать модель со связью Django

Tags: django

Добрый день. 
Начал практиковаться с django, нашел у себя старый сайтик автомобильной тематики, решил переродить его на джанге
Столкнулся с такой проблемой: 
есть несколько моделей

```
class CarsParametrTypes(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100,verbose_name = 'Название')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Параметры'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Параметры'
        db_table = 'catalog_cars_parametr_type'

class CarsParametrValues(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(CarsParametrTypes,verbose_name = 'Параметр')
    value = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = 'Значение')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Значение'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Значения'
        db_table = 'catalog_cars_parametr_values'
```

Хочу все значения параметров хранить в одной таблице
 к примеру для CarsParametrTypes такие записи Состояние, Привод, тип топлива

Далее создаю модель **Cars**

```
 class Cars(models.Model):
     model = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Модель')
     color = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Цвет')
     probeg = models.IntegerField(default = 0, verbose_name = 'Пробег')
     year = models.IntegerField(default = 0, verbose_name = 'Год выпуска')
     power = models.IntegerField(default = 0, verbose_name = 'Мощность, л.c.')
     drive = models.ForeignKey(CarsParametrValues, verbose_name = 'Привод', limit_choices_to={'type_id': 1})
```

В такой форме все работает, но если я добавляю ещэ одно поле, к примеру:

```
fuel = models.ForeignKey(CarsParametrValues, verbose_name = 'Тип топлива', limit_choices_to={'type_id': 2})
```

Тогда при создании миграции возникает ошибка. Попытки нагуглить решение, не привели к успеху: во всех рассматриваемых примерах по связям (Также пробовал указывать не `ForeignKey`, а `ManaToMany`) не обращаются дважды и более к одной и той же модели.

Comment: А зачем вообще было два раза определять связь к одной и той же таблице?

Comment: Как по мне, так это логично.Можно для каждого параметра создать отдельные таблицу, например, коробка передач, но в ней будет всего несколько записей. 
И таких параметров может быть 5-10 
А так 2 таблицы тип и значения

Comment: Ну одно дело подключить две таблицы, а другое два раза одну таблицу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При использовании нескольких `ForeignKey` к одной и той же модели, они должны иметь разные значения `related_name`

Т.е. в вашем случае это должно быть что-то такое:

```
drive = models.ForeignKey(CarsParametrValues, verbose_name = 'Привод', limit_choices_to={'type_id': 1}, related_name='drive_params')
fuel = models.ForeignKey(CarsParametrValues, verbose_name = 'Тип топлива', limit_choices_to={'type_id': 2}, related_name='fuel_params')
```

Подробнее об этом в документации Django: [здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), [здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) и [здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name).